# Render mongo data to ejs template

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

New to nodejs.  Been struggling with this basic problem.  I have some data in a mongo db.  I am using express with ejs view engine.  I can see the mongo data output from console.log.  And i know that i can insert my data in the ejs template using the following tags:  <%= variable %>, but i can't seem to figure out how to render it in the res.render code.

Here is the code that pulls data from mongo:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Connection established to', url);


    // Get the documents collection
    var collection = db.collection('car');

    // Query the collection    
     collection.find(),(function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else if (result.length) {
        console.log('Found:', result);
      } else {
        console.log('No document(s) found with defined "find" criteria!');
      }
//Close connection
      db.close();
    });
  }
});
```

This is the render section:

```
// index page
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('pages/index', {collection: result} );
});
```

And this is the ejs template:

```
<h2>Cars:</h2>
        <h3><%= result %>
```

This is the error i see in the browser:

ReferenceError: result is not defined

It is very frustrating as this should be an easy straight-forward...  I am trying to do this without using mongoose.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<%= collection %>
```

You have to use KEY instead of VALUE from json object.

Hope you have set views directory and view engine properly in express module.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your code:

1) you need to have a result object that you can pass to your view:

```
function getResult(callback) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
      } else {
        console.log('Connection established to', url);


        // Get the documents collection
        var collection = db.collection('car');

        // Query the collection    
        collection.find(),(function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else if (result.length) {
            console.log('Found:', result);
          } else {
            console.log('No document(s) found with defined "find" criteria!');
          }
          //Close connection
          db.close();
          callback(err, result);
        });
      }
   });   
}
// index page
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var result = getResult(function(err, result){
      //handle err, then you can render your view
      res.render('pages/index', {collection: result} );
  });

});
```

2) in your view you will have an object named collection (not result):

```
<h2>Cars:</h2>
    <h3><%= collection %>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have changed it to <%= collection %> in index.ejs but still getting the ReferenceError: result is not defined...

Comment: Ok i had missed the code you added for the callback.  I have since modified the code in my app.js.   I am connected to the database (as indicated by the console.log output), but the browser hangs there http://localhost:8080 and then doesn't connect...

Comment: Here is the new code with the getResult callback integrated: